# The antd Modal cannot show up when i set visible to true. Why is it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to add an upload function to my react app. And the details is when click the upload button. The modal with a table(empty at the beginning) will show up, and the table is loading, finally the data shows up after excel parsing. But after the click, i set the visible state to true, but it doesn't work, it always shows up after parsing excel.

i have added some annotations about i debug results in the code .

Finally i found that if i use

setTimeout(this.getExcelData, 100, e.file) //And the timeout cannot be too small

instead of

this.getExcelData(e.file)

the modal can show up as i wish and the 100 timeout can be ignored because the time of excel parsing is large enough.

Look like it is to do with react and modal component.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Id',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    width: "20%",
  },
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    width: "40%",
  },
  {
    title: 'Status',
    dataIndex: 'status',
    key: 'status',
    width: "40%",
  }
];

class UploadButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {visible: false,
                  excelLoading: false,
                  data: []
  }

  ...some handleOK, handleCancel function

  getExcelData = fileObj => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      ...some xlsx parse process
      this.setState({
        excelLoading: false
        data: data
      });
    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileObj);
  };

  uploadExcel = e => {
    this.setState({
      excelLoading: true,
      visible: true
    });
    this.getExcelData(e.file);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Upload beforeUpload={() => false)}
                onChange={this.uploadExcel} >
          //The button loading works here
          <Button loading={this.state.excelLoading} >upload</Button> 
        </Upload>
        //the log here is all true after upload click and setState data
        {console.log(this.state.visible)}
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          ...
        >
           //If i remove the table, the modal still shows up only after excel parsing!!!(no matter whether where is a table)
           <Table columns={columns}
                  loading={this.state.excelLoading}
                  dataSource={this.state.data} />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should not have a console.log statement inside the return of your render.. Furthermore if the modal shows up after excel uploading if you remove the table I bet it is something to do with your table and you should include that in your code.

Comment: @user254694   the console log and last annotation are wrong edit, and i have made it correct. The table setting is simple and have been added, too. And the table works fine after modal shows up.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example and don't paste snippets of code - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can make a antd-sandbox with [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96) template.